# Where is the volume step size option in Blender 2.83?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

Here is a picture of what I see in the volumes dropdown:

[image]

I tried going through all of the dropdowns in the render settings but still, no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i think the *Viewport* option is like *Step Size* but in view port and step rate is probably the same but in render mode.